# How do you keep .htaccess from being used in a particular directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website, lets say: `http://www.example.com/`

I'm using rewrite module, but I have a subfolder `forum.example.com`

I don't want the `.htaccess` to affect this directory, how do I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess not affecting other folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497997/htaccess-not-affecting-other-folders)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `forum.domain.com` points to a subdirectory like you suggested (and your current `.htaccess` file is in the directory that contains that subdirectory, or some directory above it), then all you have to do is add a `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory with the following:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

And it will disable `mod_rewrite` for any requests that point to that directory.

Answer (score 2):

In httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /relevant/directory>
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: im using a .htaccess file with no access to httpd.

how do i ignore the "RewriteRule.." on a subdomain?

Comment: @WEB I don't get it. You want to use a .htaccess file to... ignore the .htaccess files?

Comment: yes, i had an htaccess that was interrupting to the forum dir, so i needed to dismiss it

Comment: .htaccess files are read and processed from the very root of the site (/) through any subdomains or add-on domains, down the hierarchy of directories to the one in question. If you currently only have an .htaccess in the root, maybe you could add a RewriteCond as Paul Dixon below suggests, to disable whatever you're doing for just this one directory (assuming the directory is part of the URI). The alternative is to add an .htaccess in the directory of interest that somehow negates or cancels what higher-up .htaccesses are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to precede the RewriteRule with a RewriteCond directive

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
```

This way, the RewriteRule is only applied to requests matching the RewriteCond, which required the HTTP host header to match www.domain.com.
(assuming Apache 2.2; I'm not sure whether this syntax is different for previous versions).

Comment: This was an absolute life saver. Best answer no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Set [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive in the subdomain virtualhost to None

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to only apply your rule when a particular domain name is used.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.comt$ [nocase]
RewriteRule foo bar [l]
```