# .htaccess not affecting other folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file that affects my subdomains folder, how do I prevent that from happening. Want the subdomain to run independent of the .htaccess file. Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?$ goto.php?page=$1
ErrorDocument 404 PageNotFound
IndexIgnore *

####Protect the system from machines with worms 
RewriteRule (cmd|root)\.exe - [F,E=dontlog:1]

##Search Business
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} search.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^Customise/([0-9]*)/([A-Za-z-]*)$ customise.php?id=$1

#### To hold and redirect css/images/js files
RewriteRule images/(.+)?$ images/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule css/(.+)?$ css/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule js/(.+)?$ js/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule uploads/(.+)?$ uploads/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135530/urgent-how-to-stop-htaccess-to-work-on-a-subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AllowOverride` option to `None` in `httpd-conf` for your subdomains directories (see [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)).

Comment: Thanks but where exactly is the file located? Where do I set it, in the subdirectory or?

Comment: @Cyberomin It's the configuration file for your Apache instance (basically, where you configured subdomains, modules etc). Default path for Windows is `Program Files\Apache Group\Apache\conf`; for Linux it is somewhere in `/etc/conf/`. Also check out the link by Peeyush in the comment above, it's just the right thing.