# Redirect with htaccess (again) - including SSL and canonical url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, subdomain

I have a main site @ sitename.com which I need to enforce SSL and ensure the 'www' is removed if present.  This works with the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}//s%{HTTPS} ^www.(.*)//((s)on|s.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%3://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "sitename.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://sitename.com
```

However this breaks the redirects for subdomains i.e. subdomain.sitename.com now redirects to sitename.com.

Is there a simple addition to the htaccess that will force the subdomain to non-ssl and to the correct location without breaking the other logic?

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.sitename.com [L]
```

at the top of the htaccess, but this had no effect.

Comment: The original rule that you have shouldn't match against a host that's like `subdomain.domain.com`, it shouldn't match against anything that doesn't start with `www`.

Comment: True, but I think the last rule (SSL) does?  Does eq "sitename.com" include "blah.sitename.com"?

I don't want the subdomains to be forced to SSL.

Comment: If you're going to force SSL for a domain, you won't need that directive.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you're referring to.  What I need is something like:

If subdomain goto subdomain {stop rules processing} else
If domain starts with www then trim www and if protocol != SSL the force SSL.  If there any snippets of code that may help?

Comment: I found the solution [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135530/urgent-how-to-stop-htaccess-to-work-on-a-subdomain

pretty simple really :)